# php composer install private package with custom vendor name

Tags: php, composer-php

I developed a composer package, for internal use.

In the main project **composer.json**, I set to

```
"repositories":[
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:company_dev/package_name_dev.git"
    }
],
"require": {
    "company/package": "dev-master"
},
```

Due to company procedure, everything developer do, will be in a **dev** account, then merge to **production** repo before deploy to server.

Is it possible to map the `company_dev/package_name_dev.git` to `company/package`?

Because the package **composer.json** I defined

```
"name": "company/package",
```

### EDIT

After run `composer install`

```
$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
Discovered Package: cybercog/laravel-optimus
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: propaganistas/laravel-phone
Discovered Package: rtconner/laravel-tagging
Discovered Package: stechstudio/laravel-php-cs-fixer
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Nothing has changed. I don't see any error, nothing much info I get.

Comment: That should be handled automatically by Composer. When it tried to load a dependency, it should start by checking in the vcs you've added. As long as the `vendor/name` is the same it should just work.

Comment: ...have you actually tried it? If not, you should before asking. If yes and it doesn't work, please explain your issue.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I run `composer install`, but nothing is installed, no error also

Comment: That info should be in the question or we won't have a clue what you need help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the lock file, and re-run `composer install` solved my problem

```
rm composer.lock
composer install
```